# How to Force Jersey to generate Specified JSON Response

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

So, I have started using Jersey as the implementation of JAX-RS in our application for REST services and I came across a strange issue with it. We have been provided with a standard response as below:

```
"Outer":
   {
       "agencyPercentagePayment": "80",
       "agencyProviderPaymentAmount": "140.00",
       "benCoDtls":
       {
           "benCode": "String1",
           "fullName": "String2",
           "id": "String3",
           "title": "String4"
       },
       "levelOfCare": "Full-Time",
       "paymentDate": "2014-02-19T15:20",
       "titleInfo":
       {
           "benAmt": "140.0",
           "benDesc": "AAAA",
           "subTitle": "aaaa",
           "title": "String"
       },
       "units": "10"
   }
```

However, The JSON generated by the Jersey provider generates an arbitary response as below:

```
"Outer":
   {
       "agencyProviderPaymentAmount": "140.00",
       "benCoDtls": 
       {
           "benCode": "String1",
           "fullName": "String2",
           "id": "String3",
           "title": "String4"
       },
       "agencyPercentagePayment": "80",
       "titleInfo":
       {
           "benAmt": "140.0",
           "benDesc": "AAAA",
           "subTitle": "aaaa",
           "title": "String"
       },
       "paymentDate": "2014-02-19T15:20",
       "levelOfCare": "Full-Time",
       "units": "10"
   }
```

As seen above the response expects agencyPercentagePayment to be first element of Outer levelOfCare as first element after completion of benCoDtls array and paymentDate after levelOfCare, however the response is different as you see.

Any suggestions how to enforce the response generated by the Jersey Jackson Providers? I can share the Java class if required.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix this using `@XmlType` annotation:

```
 @XmlType(propOrder={"agencyPercentagePayment", "agencyProviderPaymentAmount" , ... })
 @XmlRootElement
 public class Outer {
 ....
 }
```

Comment: If this makes no difference, provide your Java classes used to marshall objects to JSON.

Comment: Did the `@XmlType` annotation make any diffrence?

Comment: Wow that worked like charm! Thanks. I have one question though. So the JSON which I showed here is a very complex structure wherein there are many arrays, if I want them in order too, do I need have each of those JAXB classes annotated with XmlRootElement and have corresponding XmlType and propOrder for them? Also just to have clear understanding, is this requirement of XmlRootElement, XmlType specific to Jersey? What if I use Spring MVC for building Rest services, will it require these annotated classes too?

Comment: These annotations come from implementation of JAXB (JSR222 implementation) which is provided within Jersey. Spring MVC is no harm to Jersey and it's JAXB implementation. But in will be wise to consult your requirements with specific framework documentation and check if it has it's own JAXB impl. and it's characteristics.

Comment: Sure, I will have a look at it. Do you think propOrder needs to be mentioned for all the Objects in the response hierarchy if the order matters?

Comment: I would recommend using `@XmlType` annotation to be sure, your JSON data will suit your application/API requirements. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved.